# Poor recording quality

Tags: audio, garageband, recording

I'm experiencing poor recording quality with an old iMac (see below) on which I recently installed High Sierra. [Here is a recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RoXgj7kGyhn3A6QlHLHl3NErLjfsXwrq/view?usp=sharing). Live acoustic/electric guitar. No effects.

I have a Scarlett 2i2 (3rd Generation) and it sounds fine just playing through it (in and out).
The recording is from Audacity, but it sounds exactly like this from GarageBand.
I tried clearing PRAM (cmd+option+P+R) on start, but it made no difference.

What else can I do?

[image: macos]

Edit: The 2i2 is [compatible with High Sierra](https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115005073725-Focusrite-product-compatibility-with-macOS-10-13-High-Sierra).
I've tried both [FocusRite Control 3.6.0 for macOS 10.12.6 or newer](https://customer.focusritegroup.com/en/support/downloads?brand=Focusrite&product_by_range=1361&download_type=all) and 3.7.4, with no difference.  Also, I just noticed the playing a youtube video with output to the 2i2 results in poor quality as well, then switching output to speakers and it is good.

[image: kHz]

Comment: I can see what's happened on the waveform, but I can't really guess at how it occurred. Some parts where you hear the crackle, the phase has suddenly inverted for a very brief moment, repeatedly over about a second. This would suggest a software issue rather than hardware. I'd check you have the correct driver version for the Scarlett/OS as playing straight through it is not the same as sending the signal to the Mac. [BTW, resetting the NVRAM will never fix anything like this - it's become a bit of an interweb meme & rarely fixes anything at all]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see addition to question. I'm not clear on the driver issue in that the 2i2 play through works without installing any driver. Perhaps it is the case that recording does require a driver. Even so, I'm not sure that the FocusRite Control tool is installing a driver, though I could be wrong, and I don't see a place on their website to download drivers.

Comment: Play-through doesn't touch the computer at all, it's all done inside the box. I'm afraid i don't know much about Focusrite USB interfaces, I've never owned one, but it is looking like a driver issue to me. Quick test - look in Applications/Utilities/Audio Midi Setup & try swapping the interface format between 44.1 & 48KHz, see if one behaves better than the other.

Comment: Oh good idea. I switched from 2 ch 24-bit Integer 44.1 to2 ch 24-bit Integer 48.0 kHz. But no joy :(  There are many choices, see addition to question. I think  may write directly to FocusRite support, see what they say.

Comment: Try 16-bit too. But yes, if no joy, contact Focusrite